# Should the Wordpress Tag be removed, since there is an entire site dedicated to it?

Tags: discussion, tags, wordpress-se

Question pretty much sums it all.

Should all questions relating to wordpress be redirected on wordpress.stackexchange.com and render the [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress) tag useless?

Comment: No, no, no, no, no. (This is from a person who has contributed but a single patch to WordPress core, though, so take the quintuple negative with a grain of salt, or five.)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn, and why would [ExpressionEngine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expressionengine) tag have such an opposite policy? *`Most ExpressionEngine questions will be better asked on the ExpressionEngine StackExchange, unless they involve development (such as developing extensions in PHP).`*

Comment: @brasofilo: Because ExpressionEngine is not WordPress...?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn, that doesn't explain the opposite policies. And it is a CMS too and has a dedicated site too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, I do not think so. You should look at the [FAQ](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) for Wordpress to see what is on-topic.

Coding which has to deal specifically with the language and not necessarily with WordPress is actually on-topic for SO.

Plugins, theming, basically anything directly connected to WordPress engine will be on-topic there.

Want to fix your Theme options? *WordPress*

Working on your PHP function (A Wordpress function), but the solution is independent of what CMS? *StackOverflow*

Moving 10,000 questions just isn't right either, consider the amount of effort mods on both sides would have to undertake to clean up migrations. Better to just leave questions (for example from 2009) where they are currently located. The scope change should only affect new and closed questions.

Comment: Exactly, moving 10,000 questions across Stack Exchange sites is simply unlike moving a million Windows Live Spaces blogs to WordPress.com. Two entirely different operations.